# \glsdesc hyperlink

Tags: glossaries, links

How can I get rid of links for `\glsdesc`, while keeping them for `\gls`? Is it possible?

(It makes no sense to link the description, since there is no extra information by going to the glossary.)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,style=listgroup]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apc} {
    name = {antigen presenting cell},
    description = {cells that present MHC proteins on their surface},
}


\begin{document}

\Glspl{apc} are \glsdesc{apc}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) provides `\glsdesc*` which removes the hyperlink:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,style=listgroup]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{apc} {
    name = {antigen presenting cell},
    description = {cells that present MHC proteins on their surface},
}


\begin{document}

\Glspl{apc} are \glsdesc*{apc}.

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

If you *never* want to hyperlink the `\glsdesc` macro, then add the following to your preamble *after* loading `glossaries`:

```
\let\oldglsdesc\glsdesc
\renewcommand{\glsdesc}{\oldglsdesc*}
```

and use `\glsdesc` as usual.

Comment: if there is \glslink in the description, they are also removed by using \glsdesc*. Any way around this?

Comment: @BenedictWilkins: I'd suggest making a small, minimal example showing your problem and ask a new question with a link to this one (since they're related in some way). See [I've just been told I have to post a follow-up question, why and how?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)